# Successfully hosted on Azure VM but not accessible throught internet

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I am having an issue with Azure VM.
As you can see I successfully run my website using `sudo dotnet TechKeeper.dll --urls="https://localhost:443"` and I keep the console open so it is still host my website.

[image: 94788-image.png]

I also have 443 exposed to the internet and running `sudo ufw allow 443`.

[image: 94815-image.png]

But when I access through the internet https://23.102.114.31:443 is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Localhost bound IP won't expose to the external network, try to bind it with URL `--urls="https://0.0.0.0:443"`. `0.0.0.0` which stands for all IP Addresses. You can access it internally and externally.

Also, you could check if any firewall blocked via Virtual machine---Connection troubleshoot---test inbound or outbound connection from Azure portal.